# Transpose groups of data in Excel or Access

Tags: sql, vba, pivot, grouping

I have a **large** group of data that looks like:

```
M.   Item   Num 
A     a      3 
A     b      2
A     c      1
B     a      4
B     b      2
B     c      3
B     d      1
C     a      1
C     b      2
```

I need to transform them into format like:

```
M.   Item    Num   Item    Num   Item    Num   Item    Num 
A     a       3      b      2      c      1
B     a       4      b      2      c      3      d      1
C     a       1      b      2
```

Comment: Changed your tagging...'pivot' is what you are looking for.  is there any upper limit to the number of items a M. can have?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I mentioned this is a large group. If you are asking number of row in the first format the number could be over 10,000. If in the second format the number of rows would be more than 800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Reformat()

    Dim arr, d1, d2, arrOut(), r As Long, ub As Long
    Dim r2 As Long, c As Long

    arr = Selection.Value 'select the source data first
    ub = UBound(arr, 1)
    Set d1 = distinct(arr, 1)
    Set d2 = distinct(arr, 2)
    ReDim arrOut(1 To d1.Count, 1 To 1 + (d2.Count * 2))

    For r = 1 To ub
        r2 = d1(arr(r, 1))
        c = 2 + (d2(arr(r, 2)) - 1) * 2
        arrOut(r2, 1) = arr(r, 1)
        arrOut(r2, c) = arr(r, 2)
        arrOut(r2, c + 1) = arr(r, 3)
    Next r

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("out")
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrOut, 1), UBound(arrOut, 2)).Value = arrOut
    End With

End Sub

'get all distinct values in a "column" of a 2-d array
Function distinct(arr As Variant, colNum) As Object
    Dim r As Long, ub As Long, i As Long, d
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ub = UBound(arr, 1)
    i = 1
    For r = 1 To ub
        If Not d.exists(arr(r, colNum)) Then
            d.Add arr(r, colNum), i
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r
    Set distinct = d
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your answer. I tried to run the macros but got a error on "ub = UBound(arr, 1)"... Please let me know if I was not using it correctly.

Comment: Did you select all of the source data before running the macro?

Comment: Does the workbook with the macro have a sheet named "out"? If not, you need to add one...